# Non blocking statements with delays

Tags: verilog

```
always@(a)
begin
#1 t<=a;
#1 c<=t;
end
```

I am analysing above verilog code with test bench as given below

```
   a=0;
#5 a=1;
#5 a=0;
#5 a=1;
#5;
```

Here is my analysis:
From above test bench I can tell that 'a' is a clock signal of total 20ns length with OFF and ON time of 5ns both respectively.At 0th ns, 'a' is changed from X to 0. So always block gets triggered.since first statement inside block is having 1ns inter delay, it waits for 1ns. after 1ns compiler gets to know that it is non blocking statement so just evaluation will be done not assignment.hence 'a' value will be stored as temporary and parallelly it executes second statement.since second one also has inter delay,it waits for 1ns. and then evaluation is done.since both the evaluations are done, assignment will happen now.

```
    time   a   t   c
    0ns    0   x   x
    1ns    0   x   x
    2ns    0   x   x
    3ns    0   0   x
    4ns    0   0   x
```

is this analysis correct?

Comment: *"my analysis is wrong when compared to actual output"* In that case I suggest you start with telling us what your analysis is. Until then we can't tell you where you are going wrong.

Comment: (x) in this code,assume 'a' gets changed from x to 0 initially. so always block gets triggered.while executing first statement compiler gets to know that it is non blocking statement, hence value of 'a' is assigned with temporary varibale but not yet assigned to 't'. since it is non blocking, parallely it executes second statement.but second statement is having inter delay of 1ns, so after 1ns it executes. that is, 't' gets evaluated. so after these two evaluations only, final assignment of 't' and 'a' will happen. is my analysis right here?

Comment: Please add your text to the question (use the 'edit' button underneath) You realise that leaving `t` out of the sensitivity list is not normal?

Comment: i completely rewrote the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not what happens, non-blocking assignments work different then what you describe.

You are right in that the actual assignment of a non-blocking statement is deferred, executed "later". But when is "later"?

'non-blocking' events are processed when there are no more outstanding blocking events. But before processing delays. Thus as soon as the simulator sees that it has to process your `#1`, it first handles all non-blocking assignments and only then start processing the delay.
Which means even before it starts the `#1` delay `t` already has received the value of `a`.

There is a whole chapter in the Verilog standard which describes in what order the various 'actions' should be performed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. where can i read more about blocking and non blocking statements scheduling criteria. because i want to understand more with intra and inter delays specified in blocking and non blocking statements. any best epdf??

Comment: I downloaded the System-Verilog 3.1a standard a long time ago. Try to find it and look at Section 14.

Comment: The SystemVerilog 3.1standard is 15 years obsolete. You can download the latest version for free at https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595

Comment: Just tried: IEEE asks for emails etc. It may be free but you first have give up your privacy... No, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to re-write your `always` block into separate lines and sightly move the location of the `begin/end` blocks. This has no affect on behavior as everything is executed sequentially.

```
always // instantiate a procedural block
      begin
      @a  // blocking event delay waits for a change on -a-
      #1  // blocking time delay waits for 1 time unit
      t <= a; // non-blocking assignment 
              // uses the current value of -a- one time unit after it changed
              // and schedules an assignment to t
      #1 // blocking time delay waits for 1 time unit
         // since there is no more active things to do -a- gets updated
      c <= a; // uses the updated value of t and schedules an assignment to c
      end // now 2 time units after -a- was first changed
          // goes back to the top of the block and waits for another change 
          // on -a-.
```

Note that any changes on **a** that happen while executing the block are missed. Here's a good [presentation on non-blocking assignments](http://www.sutherland-hdl.com/papers/1996-CUG-presentation_nonblocking_assigns.pdf).